# Suggestion with fixing my code

Tags: c++

I have to read an input file calls_history.txt that is like this

```
Mo  13:30   16
Mo  8:15    35
Tu  7:50    20
We  17:45   30
Th  8:00    45
Su  23:50   30
```

And then calculate the cost of each calls.
So far, this is what I got.

```css
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    string filename, day, Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa, Su;
    int duration;

    string time_start;
    int hour_start, minute_start;
    double TotalCost, cost_1, cost_2;

    cout << "Enter filename: ";
    cin >> filename;

    cout << "Day" << "\tTime" << "\tDuration" << "\tCost" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl;

    inFile.open (filename.c_str());
    string line;

    if (inFile)
    {
//read records from file
    while (getline (inFile, line))
    {
        stringstream iss(line);

     //split into 3 fields
        while(iss)
    {
        iss >> day;
        iss >> hour_start;
        iss >> minute_start;
        iss >> duration;
    }
        if (day == "Mo" || day == "Tu" || day == "We" || day == "Th" || day == "Fr")
        {
                if (hour_start >= 8 && hour_start <= 18)
                {
                    TotalCost = duration*0.40;
                }
                if ((hour_start = 7, minute_start < 60) && (minute_start+duration >= 60))
                {
                    cost_1 = (60-minute_start)*0.25;
                    cost_2 = ((duration-(60-minute_start))*0.40);
                    TotalCost = cost_1+cost_2;
                }
                if (hour_start < 8 && hour_start >= 18)
                {
                    TotalCost = duration*0.25;
                }
        }
        if (day == "Sa" || day == "Su")
        {
                if ((hour_start =23 && minute_start <60)&& (minute_start+duration >=60))
                {
                    cost_1 = (60-minute_start)*0.15;
                    cost_2 = ((duration-(60-minute_start))*0.25);
                    TotalCost = cost_1+cost_2;
                }
                else
                {
                    TotalCost = duration*0.15;
                }
        }

     cout << day << "\t" << hour_start <<":" << minute_start << "\t" << duration << "\t\t$";
     cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << TotalCost << endl;

        inFile.close();
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tested it out and only got this result

```css
Enter filename: calls_history.txt
Day     Time    Duration        Cost
----------------------------------------------
Mo      7:30    16              $6.40

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.622 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Any suggestion so that I can show all the other lines and datas?
I have to make it look like this

```css
Day Time Duration Cost
Mo 13:30 16         $6.40
Mo 8:15 35         $14.00
Tu 7:50 20         $6.50
We 17:45 30         $9.75
Th 8:00 45         $18.00
Su 23:50 30         $6.50
Total                         $61.15
```

Comment: Did you step through the code, line-by-line, in the debugger?

Comment: `if (day == "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr")` really?

Comment: yes, obviously I am a noob

Comment: This may be of help: https://www.mochima.com/tutorials/conditionals.html Consider getting a recommended book: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of bad placement of the file closing.

```
while (getline(inFile, line))
{
    ...parsing...
    inFile.close();
}
```

You want:

```
while (getline(inFile, line))
{
    ...parsing...
}
inFile.close();
```

But you don't need to explicitly close the file anyway. `ifstream`s destructor will take care of it when inFile goes out of scope at the end of the function.

The next problem you'll run into:

```
iss >> day; // read stream up to whitespace into string
iss >> hour_start; // read stream until not int into int
iss >> minute_start; // read stream until not int into int
iss >> duration; // read stream until not int into int
```

The input:

```
Mo  13:30   16
```

What happens:

```
iss >> day; // reads "Mo"
iss >> hour_start; // reads 13
iss >> minute_start; // tries to read ':' as int, fails
iss >> duration; // previous error not cleared. Fails
```

The read failures were not tested for and handled. Minute start and duration are used unassigned. Comic hi-jinks ensue.

Try instead:

```
char colon;
if (iss >> day >> hour_start >> colon >> minute_start >> duration && (colon == ':'))
{
     do calculations
}
else
{
    notify user of bad file
}
```